# Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, ......) iOS 10.1

Tags: ios, exc-bad-access

I am running the iOS App in simulator but it is getting crash with the EXC_BAD_ACCESS on the following line of code.

```
NSMutableData *data = [receivedData objectForKey:connection.tagKey];
```

the block of code is as follows:

```
- (NSMutableData*)dataForConnection:(URLConnection*)connection {
NSMutableData *data = [receivedData objectForKey:connection.tagKey];
return data;
}
```

Thank you in advance for the help.

Comment: Please post more code. It is hard to tell what you are doing. What is receivedData and where is it being initialized.

Comment: @Siriss Thank you for your reply. receivedData is being initialized in the start of file as follow. interface myInterfaceCall ()<NSURLConnectionDelegate> { NSMutableData* responseData; NSMutableDictionary* receivedData; NSString* APITag; NSString* url; URLConnection* urlConnection; NSString* baseUrl; NSString* postData; } end

Comment: Post all your delegates. Form your description, you are trying to assign NSMutabeData to an object in a NSMutableDictionary.

Comment: @Yas It might crash if your dictionary `receivedData` don't have `connection.tagKey`. Just print the response dictionary and check. If this not the case then update your answer with crash log.